# Should i create one or two app on facebook to use "login with facebook"

Tags: android, django, facebook, oauth, django-allauth

I'am adding the feature "login with facebook" to a **mobile** app. This feature is already existing on the **web** server. So the web server is already registered on my facebook developer page.

Should i create  a new "mobile app" on facebook or should i use **only** the web server parameters registered on facebook and inject them in the "mobile app" ?

The Parameters are "App Id" "App key" "secret key"

NB1: The server is based on django, django-allauth.

NB2: The app is based on cordova and its plugins

Thank you for your advices

Comment: You would get different app-scoped user ids, if you used different app ids - and that is rather likely not something you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the mobile platform in the App settings, you do not need a new App.

Comment: Thank you,  for the 1st time i click on "Add platform". I will investigate right now. Thanks